# How to mount files to a folder with existing files in a pod?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, configmap

I have a Spring boot application that is packaged in an image and run by a command in docker file

```
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "java $JAVA_OPTS -jar /deployments/app.jar" ]
```

I also have a ConfigMap that contains a fileTest.yml file

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2016-02-18T19:14:38Z
  name: app-sample-config
  namespace: myproject
data: 
  fileTest.yml: |-
    owner:
      name: Eva
      surname: Bosh
    library:
      books:
        -
          author: J. K. Rowling
          name: Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone
        -
          author: J. R. R. Tolkien
          name: The Hobbit
```

I'm trying to mount a file as a volume. It should be located in the same directory as the jar. But if I specify the configuration as below, I get an error `Error: Unable to access jarfile /deployments/app.jar`

```
kind: DeploymentConfig
    apiVersion: v1
    metadata:
      name: app-test
    spec:
      replicas: 1
      selector:
        app: app-test
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: app-test
        spec:
          volumes:
            - name: app-sample-vol
              configMap:
                name: app-sample-config
          containers:
            - name: app-test
              volumeMounts:
                - mountPath: /deployments/
                  name: app-sample-vol
```

If I change the `mountPath: /deployments/` to `mountPath: /deployments/fileTest.yml`, I get an error `as a directory`. `fileTest.yml` is created as a directory.

Is it possible to place `fileTest.yml` in the same directory where jar (without  `subPath`)?

I can't use subPath since I need to auto-reload the config map

Comment: If we mount the full config map into a folder, the content of the folder gets overridden with the content from the configmap. For this, we can change the `mountPath` to `/deployments/fileTest.yml` and add, for example `subPath: fileTest.yml` to the `volumeMount`-entry. This mounts the specific entry (`fileTest.yml`) form the configmap into `/deployments/fileTest.yml`. See the [corresponding kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#using-subpath).

Comment: @Turing85, Unfortunately, the documentation says: "A container using a ConfigMap as a subPath volume mount will not receive ConfigMap updates. " https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/#mounted-configmaps-are-updated-automatically". I need to get ConfigMap changes. Is it impossible to have files and jar in one place?

Comment: Yes. As I said: if we mount the whole configmap in a directory, it "shadows" the content of the directory (this is why we do not see the jar in the example).

Comment: A possible solution would be to re-deploy the deployment whenever the configmap is updated. I'd imagine that the deployment process is automated, hence it would "only" be an additional step in the process.